# Prove that if $f$ is a rational function then it can not have a jump discontinuity.

Tags: calculus, continuity, rational-functions

Prove that if $f$ is a rational function then it can not have a jump discontinuity.

I have seen many questions similar(but necessarily not exactly the same) to that question here but I still can not figure what are the rigor steps of this proof.

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jump discontinuity is a point where the function has finite limits from the left as well as from the right and these two are not equal. If $f$ is a rational function it is  a ratio of two polynomials say $f=\frac p q$. At any point $x$ where $q(x) \neq 0$ the function is continuous. At point where $q(x)=0$ and $p(x) \neq 0$ the function does not have finite limits from left or right. The case when $p(x)=0=q(x)$ can be avoided by cancelling  out any common factors between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: what if there are no common factors between p &q ..... how can I deal with this case?

Comment: If there are no common factors then $p$ and $q$ cannnot  both vanish at the same point.  This is what I used in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Proof: A rational function cannot have a jump discontinuity because it is continuous at every point of its domain (since it is the quotient of two continuous functions).

Comment: but I think that jump discontinuities are for points at which the function is undefined like $f(x) = \frac{1/x - 1/(x+1)}{1/(x-1) - 1/x}$ at list this is the definition in my book ..... John Petrovic

Comment: No. A jump discontinuity is a point $a$ of the domain such $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists but it is different from $f(a)$.

Comment: The definition is on p.61 of my book at the top of the page.

Comment: I am talking about **jump** discontinuities. And what does it matter that it appears on page 61 of your book if you don't tell me what that book is?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you are confusing removable with jump. A point where $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, but it is not equal to $f(a)$ (sometimes is used even when $f(a)$ is not defined) is called a removable discontinuity. A jump discontinuty is one where the left limit and the right limit exists, are finite, and different.